# twitter-python - Getting an error following the Documentation

Tags: python, twitter

Under python2.7 and already installed the requirements.txt from the [twitter-python Building section](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter)

It's the first time I'm jumping in, and following the basics steps to ensure is everything okay as described here in this link [twitter-python Documentation section](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter), I'm getting an error.

Here the typen at command line Python shell:

```
>>> api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',
                   consumer_secret='consumer_secret',
                   access_token_key='access_token',
                   access_token_secret='access_token_secret')
```

The error:

```
>>> print api.VerifyCredentials()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/twitter/local/lib/python2.7/site-  packages/python_twitter-1.2-py2.7.egg/twitter.py", line 5209, in VerifyCredentials
data = self._ParseAndCheckTwitter(json.content)
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/twitter/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_twitter-1.2-py2.7.egg/twitter.py", line 5462, in _ParseAndCheckTwitter
self._CheckForTwitterError(data)
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/twitter/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_twitter-1.2-py2.7.egg/twitter.py", line 5487, in _CheckForTwitterError
raise TwitterError(data['errors'])
twitter.TwitterError: [{u'message': u'Invalid or expired token', u'code': 89}]
```

What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace `'consumer_key'`, `'consumer_secret'`, `'access_token'`, and `'access_token_secret'` with their actual values. You can either put those values directly in the `twitter.Api()` call, or assign their values to variables:

```
>>> # all these values are just random, you'll need to use your own values
>>> c_key = '123456'
>>> c_secret = 'a88d098cd76'
>>> token = '98765'
>>> token_secret = 'ad98c63e87f00'
>>> api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=c_key,
                      consumer_secret=c_secret,
                      access_token_key=token,
                      access_token_secret=token_secret)
```

Comment: oh I see! How blind I was!? I thought that would work magically like things usually do in programming terms. Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but it looks like you need a valid consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key and access_token_secret. This will involve you setting up your own app on twitter.com and using the consumer keys/secrets and test access_token keys/secrets to get started.